# Small gap between img tag and border

Tags: html, css

So I've set my image tag with css property `border:black 2px solid;`
Apparently it has a small gap on it

[image]

I have tried:
Turn img to `display:block;` and removing gap in the html file. Any idea what causes this? and how to fix it. From what I've known inline kinda treat the element like text so it has a small gap for text descendants that's why it has the gap at the bottom and  the small gaps on the side was caused by spacing between inline and block element.

By turning the img tag to block and removing blank space in html like this `<div><img></div>` doesn't fix this because i added border directly to the img tag it self.

I wonder if this is normal it only appears during browser zoomed out 75% and zoomed in 125%

This one even appear on 100% zoomed browser

[image]

```css
:root {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.page-wrapper {
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
/* Styling Heading */
.heading-wrapper{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.heading-wrapper > img {
    height: 100%;
    width : 100%;
    display:block;
    border: black 2px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* image list */

.img-list-wrapper {
    display:block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.img-list-wrapper > .image-wrapper {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    display:block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-list-wrapper > .image-wrapper > img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}



/* effect */

.effect {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="heading-wrapper">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/800" alt="Main Heading">
        </div>
        <div class="img-list-wrapper">
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="img/image1.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="img/image1.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrapper effect">
                <img  src="https://picsum.photos/800">
            </div>
            
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="img/image1.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="img/image1.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="img/image1.jpeg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

feel free to ask for additional information if you need one.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use https://picsum.photos/ for dummy images

Comment: Added dummy pic

Comment: Looks like a glitch in Chrome to me. Displayed fine on Firefox at any zoom level

Comment: Looks good to mee to. Try in incognito mode, maybe some kind of chrome extension did that trick. You also can try to add `font-size: 0; line-height: 0;` - for image wrapper, it can also help if some kind of typograhy styles add that spacing

Comment: I have tried font-size and line height still the same i was using Edge and Chrome browser. @julien.giband we're right it works on firefox

Comment: @Vaness if you tested the new Edge, it uses Webkit as engine, like Chrome

Comment: So it's normal to behave like this then for webkit engine

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page-wrapper {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}


/* Styling Heading */

.heading-wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/* image list */

.img-list-wrapper {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.img-list-wrapper>.image-wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
}


/* effect */

.effect {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="heading-wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800);">
    </div>
    <div class="img-list-wrapper">
      <div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(img/image1.jpeg);">
      </div>
      <div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(img/image1.jpeg);">
      </div>
      <div class="image-wrapper effect" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800);">
      </div>
      <div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(img/image1.jpeg);">
      </div>
      <div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(img/image1.jpeg);">
      </div>
      <div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(img/image1.jpeg);">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please also add an explanation, not just working code

Comment: @John Skiles Skinner Sorry for my English. My primary language is Russian.
With regard to this decision.
In this case, an image is used inside a layer (div), the path of which is specified using a style. No unnecessary tags and hassles. This is my logic and this is the first thing that came to my mind. And this solution works for me.

Comment: @John Skiles Skinne Also, with the help of styles, you can create different versions of the download and additional solutions, if, for example, the image did not load.
P.S. guys, please help me with the work who has such an opportunity. I'm out of money.